# Creating a generic CodeClass with EnvDTE

Tags: c#, visual-studio, envdte

Is it possible to create a CodeClass with a type parameter (e.g., `MyClass<T> where T : struct`) using the EnvDTE interface?

Passing a name with a generic parameter to the namespace `AddClass` method results in an error that the name is invalid.

As a workaround, I have attempted creating the class without generics using the `AddClass` method and then adding the type parameters (and type constraints) as text using the `EditPoint` interface. However, this breaks the code model so that additional edits (such as adding methods) cannot be performed.

The add-in is targeting Visual Studio 2012.